# how can we set minimum height of collepsed bottomsheet

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

I can successfully add peak height but when trying to set minimum height of the bottom sheet, i am unable to do so, and whole sheet got collepsed.
so i tried to make it expanded on state hidden but it is not enough for me, as it goes too heigh.

My Main concern is to not hide the bottomsheet any how if get hidden or collapsed it has to reappear and set a minimum height

please suggest something:

below is my code :

```
final View bottomSheet = findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet2);
    mBottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
    mBottomSheetBehavior.setHideable(true);
    mBottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);

    mBottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(View bottomSheet, int newState) {
            if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) {

            }
            else if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN) {
                mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
            }
            else if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED) {

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSlide(View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
        }
    });
```

and hare is my xml:

```
        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:background="#00ffffff"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:elevation="6dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Rohit Lalwani"
                        android:id="@+id/postedBy"
                        android:textSize="16dp"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:textColor="#333"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Ad posted Yesterday"
                        android:id="@+id/postedTime"
                        android:textSize="13dp"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:textColor="#333"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1px"
                    android:background="@color/color2"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/Price"
                    android:text="₹ 2,00,000"
                    android:padding="15dp"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/color1"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/ProdName"
                    android:text="product name"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:textSize="14dp"
                    android:textColor="#333"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1px"
                    android:background="@color/color2"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0px"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="0px"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:textSize="16dp"
                            android:textColor="@color/color2"
                            android:id="@+id/cat1Icon"
                            android:text="55"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="0px"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="4"
                            android:textSize="16dp"
                            android:textColor="@color/color2"
                            android:id="@+id/cat1Text"
                            android:text="categeory1"/>

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0px"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="0px"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:textSize="16dp"
                            android:textColor="@color/color2"
                            android:id="@+id/cat2Icon"
                            android:text="55"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="0px"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="4"
                            android:textSize="16dp"
                            android:textColor="@color/color2"
                            android:id="@+id/cat2Text"
                            android:text="categeory2"/>

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0px"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="0px"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:textSize="16dp"
                            android:textColor="@color/color2"
                            android:id="@+id/cat3Icon"
                            android:text="55"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="0px"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="4"
                            android:textSize="16dp"
                            android:textColor="@color/color2"
                            android:id="@+id/cat3Text"
                            android:text="categeory1"/>

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0px"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="0px"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:textSize="16dp"
                            android:textColor="@color/color2"
                            android:id="@+id/cat4Icon"
                            android:text="55"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="0px"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="4"
                            android:textSize="16dp"
                            android:textColor="@color/color2"
                            android:id="@+id/cat4Text"
                            android:text="categeory2"/>

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0px"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="0px"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:textSize="16dp"
                            android:textColor="@color/color2"
                            android:id="@+id/cat5Icon"
                            android:text="55"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="0px"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="4"
                            android:textSize="16dp"
                            android:textColor="@color/color2"
                            android:id="@+id/cat5Text"
                            android:text="categeory1"/>

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0px"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="0px"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:textSize="16dp"
                            android:textColor="@color/color2"
                            android:id="@+id/cat6Icon"
                            android:text="55"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="0px"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="4"
                            android:textSize="16dp"
                            android:textColor="@color/color2"
                            android:id="@+id/cat6Text"
                            android:text="categeory2"/>

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1px"
                    android:background="@color/color2"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="10dp"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/color2"
                        android:id="@+id/distance"
                        android:text="5 Km away"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="12dp"
                        android:id="@+id/location"
                        android:textColor="#333"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:text="Alwar, Basant Vihar"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1px"
                    android:background="@color/color2"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/description"
                    android:text="Full description about the product"
                    android:padding="10sp"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 9):

You just need to define behavior_peekHeight to and behavior_hideable to false as example below:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
android:id="@+id/ores_bottom_sheet"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="200dp"
app:behavior_hideable="false"
app:behavior_peekHeight="90dp">
```

Comment: In my case somebody set `bottomSheetBehavior.peekHeight = 100` in code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using paddingBottom instead of layout_marginBottom inside your NestedScrollView. Sometimes the layout understands spacing better when you use padding. If that doesn't work, try wrapping the NestedScrollView in another layout view (FrameLayout, LinearLayout, etc) and put the margin or padding on that view. That way the outer view will always retain the minimum height.

Comment: i want to set minimum height of bottomsheet